# PHP CURL, Command Line

Tags: php, shell, curl

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token token=<your_private_token>' -X POST
-F job[webapp_id]=2
-F job[param]=""
-F files[0]=@test.txt
-F files[1]=@test2.csv
-F job[file_url]="http://www.lirmm.fr/DEMAR/images/inria_corpo_rvb.jpg"
-F job[dataset]=<my_dataset_name> https://allgo.inria.fr/api/v1/jobs
```

I want to convert this into PHP cURL format. I have tried out something but it isn't working properly. Really would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried?